# unable to open sqlite database ionic framework

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I added this plugings from ionic framework doc

```
> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage <br>npm install
> @ionic-native/sqlite
```

At my app module.ts i imported  and inject  to provider

```
> import { *SQLite*, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx';<br><br>
> providers: [
   StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
>     { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },SQLite,Allconnection],
```

At mymainpage.ts

> ```
> import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx';
>  import {Platform} from '@ionic/angular';
>  declare var window;
>
>
>
>  constructor
>     (private sqlite: SQLite,public platform: Platform){                                                    
>        this.platform.ready().then (()=>{
>       var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'my.db', location: 'default' }, function (db) {
>   }, function (error) {
>       console.log('Open database ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
>   });
> })
>  }
> ```

i got this error when i run it on chrome browser

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

try moving SQLite under into the providers array like such.

```
> import { *SQLite*, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx';<br><br>
> providers: [
   StatusBar,
   SQLite
   SplashScreen,
>     { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },Allconnection],
```

you have to make sure the npm module is added to the list of providers any time you add a ionic native plugin.

Comment: thanks alot,..but i got this error Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'SQLite' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Comment: make sure your import path is correct. check the ionic docs to make sure you have the right path for your node module.

Comment: thanks alot i will still cheak out,..just that i followed theionic  doc https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/sqlite/

Comment: this is the import for v3 import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';

Comment: which one should i use pls

Comment: if your useing ionic 3 import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite ionic 4 and above has a different import